# Accessing objects in client side javascript in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In express if I passed an object into an jade file like so

```
res.render("index",{name : "Kerrigan"});
```

I can access the name property of the literal object in index.jade like this

```
p My name is #{name}
```

However in order to access the literal object in a client side script I would have to initially do this.

```
script(type="text/javascript").
  name = !{JSON.stringify(name)};
  //now I can use the name variable
  alert(name);
```

So my question is what does the `!{JSON.stringify(name)}` line do, and how is the `!` operator being used here?
I am new to express and javascript, so I believe it has something to do with how the `res.render` function sends the object to jade.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *access* the object from the client side javascript, you *inject* the value of the object in the script. You should have a look at the generated page to see this point.

I wish I could point you the documentation of `!{}`, but it seems there is no documentation on that one ...

`!{expression}` injects the value of the expression, not escaped (the meaning of `!` in jade in *unescaped*). `#{expression}` does the same thing but escape the value.